# Parse string as CSV with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm doing an API request that returns me a really long string in CSV format. Here's two lines :

```
Backup ID,Account,Account Number,Snapshot Account,Snapshot Account Number,Policy,Status,Region,Type,Volume/DB/Cluster,Volume/DB/Cluster Name,Instance,Instance Name,Snapshot ID,Succeeded,Start Time,End Time,Deleted At,Volume Size (GB),Valid Data Size (GB),Changed Data Size (GB)
1542,Account Goes Here,Account Nmber Goes Here,Snapshot Account Goes Here,Snapshot Account Number Goes Here,Policy Goes Here,All Snapshots Deleted,Region Goes Here,Type Goes Here,Volume Goes Here,Volume Name Goes Here,Instance Goes Here,Instance Name Goes Here,Snapshot ID Goes Here,Yes,06/15/2020 06:00:35 PM,06/15/2020 06:02:18 PM,06/22/2020 06:27:18 PM,Volume Size Goes Here,N/A,Unknown
1542,Account Goes Here,Account Nmber Goes Here,Snapshot Account Goes Here,Snapshot Account Number Goes Here,Policy Goes Here,All Snapshots Deleted,Region Goes Here,Type Goes Here,Volume Goes Here,Volume Name Goes Here,Instance Goes Here,Instance Name Goes Here,Snapshot ID Goes Here,Yes,06/15/2020 06:00:35 PM,06/15/2020 06:02:18 PM,06/22/2020 06:27:18 PM,200,N/A,Unknown
```

I want to parse this string and place it in an array.

The size of this string can vary since it is generated each day.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `explode()` to split the string into lines. Then write a loop that calls `str_getcsv()` on each line and processes it.

Comment: If the two values always have the same keys ("are always at the same place"), why the need to loop, since you already know the keys?

Comment: Sorry to respond this late, I was in week-end :)
Well I'm not an expert in PHP, I just tought it was a good idea to loop through the line, like @d3javu99 did. But why are you downvoting my question ? That's not really justified I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem using the following code:

```php
function treatString() {
    // Parsing the string as array
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
    $reports = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $reports[] = str_getcsv($line);

        // doing something then...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$f = file(...your csv file...);
foreach($f as $k => $line) {
    if ($k > 0) //we skip the first one
    {
        $results = explode(',', $line);
        //at this stage $results is a flat array
        // var_dump($result);
        ... do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I really want : as said, a method returns me a **string**, not a file.

Comment: you then have 2 options, write into a file and load as I explained in my comment or
use the explode() function in a way that will return lines and for each line you will use the explode again
or...option 3 read the documentation of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php